# What's the purpose of the following postgresql stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

What's the purpose of the following postgresql stored procedure, it's used when execute a query, thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_fp_query(int[]) RETURNS int[]
AS $$
    SELECT uniq(sort(subarray($1 - 627964279,
        greatest(0, least(icount($1 - 627964279) - 120, 80)), 120)));
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Comment: What do you understand from reading the [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/index.html) manual on the `uniq`, `sort`, `subarray`, `greatest`, `least` and `icount` functions.  When you have a specific question on those, people can help you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't know if this makes the question better or worse but: AFAIK only `greatest` and `least` are explained in the PostgreSQL manual. `uniq`, `sort`, `subarray` and `icount` must be other user supplied functions.

Comment: @A.H.: If they're non-standard functions, the question is unanswerable by anyone without access to the user-supplied functions.  However, I found some material in the PostgreSQL manual: [`sort`, `icount`, `subarray`, and `uniq`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/intarray.html).

Comment: sorry, the real point confusing me is the '$1 - 627964279', how can an array sub a integer..I 'm a c programmer and not good at sql, store procedure and so on, thank you~

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, they're part of the `intarray` contrib module, which is bundled with the server but not loaded by default. It's loaded with `CREATE EXTENSION intarray;`

Comment: @magicyang What significance does the "magic number" 627964279 have?

Comment: I had written an answer too. I think I even found a flaw in the function, but unfortunately the guys closed the question before I could post (an overzealous move I disagree with, btw.). Can't post my answer now, so here goes the short version: I suspect, your function should look like this:

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.extract_fp_query(int[]) RETURNS int[]
    AS $$
       SELECT subarray(arr, GREATEST(0, LEAST(icount(arr) - 120, 80)), 120)
       FROM (SELECT uniq(sort($1 - 627964279)) AS arr) x
    $$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;

Comment: **This is what the function does:** "Return up to 120 unique, sorted elements of the input array. 627964279 is removed. If the array is longer, trim up to 80 elements from the start before truncating the rest." It counts *before* removing duplicates, which I suspect is a bug. Consider my improved version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter OK, nominated for re-opening. I don't really agree (the OP could've at least provided context - like function inputs, how/where it's called, etc), but I'll go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code relies heavily on functionality in [the `intarray` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html). Once you know that you can work it out by breaking it down into steps.

It looks to me like some kind of poor-man's crypto or obfuscation routine, but you've failed to provide any information about its inputs so it's hard to say more. Essentially it returns a sorted, de-duplicated subset of the passed array, deciding which subset to return based on the number of elements in the array. If I read it correctly it removes the value 627964279 from the array if it appears there, then returns 120 elements (before de-duplication) from an offset of 0 and 80 elements into the array depending on the number of elements in the array.

Create a test database. I'll call mine `regress`. Create it and install the `intarray` contrib module into it as a superuser:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb -O myusername regress
sudo -u postgres psql regress -c 'CREATE EXTENSION intarray;'
```

Now running as `myusername`, whatever your unpriveleged user account is, break the code down into steps and try each step. Just like you would in C. It might help to format it into expressions:

```
SELECT uniq(sort(
    subarray(
        $1 - 627964279,
        greatest(
            0, 
            least(
                icount($1 - 627964279) - 120,
                80
            )
        )
        , 120
    )
));
```

then evaluate each sub-expression by hand with a known input, substituting results as you go and simplifying the expression while jotting down what it does. I can't do it for you because you haven't supplied a sample input, but, replacing `ARRAY[42,5,9,24,1,627964279]` with your input array you'd do something like:

```
$ psql regress
psql (9.2.1)
Type "help" for help.

regress=> SELECT ARRAY[42,5,9,24,1,627964279];
          array          
-------------------------
 {42,5,9,24,1,627964279}
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT ARRAY[42,5,9,24,1,627964279] - 627964279;
   ?column?    
---------------
 {42,5,9,24,1}
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT icount(ARRAY[42,5,9,24,1,627964279] - 627964279);
 icount 
--------
      5
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT least(icount(ARRAY[42,5,9,24,1,627964279] - 627964279),80);
 least 
-------
     5
(1 row)

regress=> 
regress=> SELECT greatest(least(icount(ARRAY[42,5,9,24,1,627964279] - 627964279),80),0);
 greatest 
----------
        5
(1 row)
```

Now, by substituting `5` for the expression `greatest(...)` into the `subarray` expression we get:

```
SELECT subarray($1 - 627964279, 5, 120 )
```

which is after the evaluation of the array item removal:

```
regress=> SELECT subarray(ARRAY[42,5,9,24,1], 5, 120);
 subarray 
----------
 {1}
(1 row)
```

In this case the `sort` and `uniq` have no further effect.

What's it for? Who knows, as you haven't provided an input array that might offer clues.

See [the intarray documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html).